# How to get count repeated data in row in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, row

My table has many columns, among them `attendance` and `register`

- if employee present its to update day1 = '1' and
- if employee present its to update day2 = '1' and
- if employee absent its to update day3 = '2' and etc.,
- if Sunday its to update day5='0'

Here my table:

```
Employee id | Month | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4| day5| ......| day31
      1     |  Jan  |  1   |   1  |  2   |   1 |  0  | ......|  1   
      2     |  Jan  |  2   |   1  |  2   |   1 |  1  | ......|  1
```

I want to get Employee id  = 1,

```
How to Count present days  and absent days ?
```

Comment: What about a month which doesn't have 31 days?

Comment: April has 30 days only so day 31 as '0'

Comment: Really awful table design. Please reconsider it. First of all most database engines implement boolean types as 0 is false and <> 0 is true so it'd help you to change values like that. But most of all why not use simple EmployeeID | Date table and if there is a record then employee was present on that day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `Decode` function

```
select Decode(day1, 1, 1, 0) + -- <- treat 1 as 1, all other values as 0
       Decode(day2, 1, 1, 0) +
       Decode(day3, 1, 1, 0) + 
       ... 
       Decode(day31, 1, 1, 0) as PresentCount,
       Decode(day1, 2, 1, 0) + -- <- treat 2 as 1, all other values as 0
       Decode(day2, 2, 1, 0) +
       Decode(day3, 2, 1, 0) + 
       ... 
       Decode(day31, 2, 1, 0) as AbsentCount 
  from MyTable
 where (Employee_Id = 1)
 -- and (Month = 'Feb') -- <- uncomment this if you want February only
```

P.S. Probably you should re-design your table

Comment: @Murtaza: The question doesn't mention month, so I've summed up all the data for Employee_Id = 1. However, it seems to be easy to add a filter on month (see my edit). There's however one problem - how to filter out a year...

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNPIVOT` to transform columns to rows. For more information on this see [the article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html). Below is example of usage for your case:

```
with t as (
select 1234 emp_id,
       'Feb' mon,
       2 day1,
       1 day2,
       2 day3,
       1 day4,
       2 day5,
       1 day6,
       2 day7,
       1 day8,
       2 day9,
       1 day10,
       2 day11,
       1 day12,
       2 day13,
       1 day14,
       2 day15,
       1 day16,
       2 day17,
       1 day18,
       2 day19,
       1 day20,
       2 day21,
       1 day22,
       2 day23,
       1 day24,
       2 day25,
       1 day26,
       2 day27,
       1 day28,
       0 day29,
       0 day30,
       0 day31 from dual)
select emp_id,
       mon,
       sum(nullif(presence_code, 2)) presence_count,
       sum(nullif(presence_code, 1)) / 2 absence_count
  from (select *
          from t unpivot(presence_code for presence_day in (day1,
                                                            day2,
                                                            day3,
                                                            day4,
                                                            day5,
                                                            day6,
                                                            day7,
                                                            day8,
                                                            day9,
                                                            day10,
                                                            day11,
                                                            day12,
                                                            day13,
                                                            day14,
                                                            day15,
                                                            day16,
                                                            day17,
                                                            day18,
                                                            day19,
                                                            day20,
                                                            day21,
                                                            day22,
                                                            day23,
                                                            day24,
                                                            day25,
                                                            day26,
                                                            day27,
                                                            day28,
                                                            day29,
                                                            day30,
                                                            day31))) q
 group by emp_id, mon;

    EMP_ID MON PRESENCE_COUNT ABSENCE_COUNT
---------- --- -------------- -------------
      1234 Feb             14            14
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer to your question.

But how about you use one integer column to represent all present days?

e.g.:

Value 1: Is present on Day1

Value 3: Is present on Day1 and Day2

Value 8: Is present on Day4

So you can change your table layout to:

> Employee id | Month | openDays

Integer fits perfectly to store up to 31 days (it could even save up to 32 days).

Comment: thanks for your answer i can't use 1 for present i stored other primary key here but i put '2' for absent....